# how to render user to Home with name in URL after login?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, url

Im trying to show username in URL like "localhost:1001/Home/Jay" After post login form

this in user.js code

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) =>  res.render('login'));

app.get('/Home/:name', function(req, res){
    res.render('Home');
    console.log(req.params.name)
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var pass = req.body.pass;

    let errors = [];

    if(name == ''){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Please Enter Name' });
    }

    if(pass == ''){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Please Enter Password' });
    }

    req.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM App WHERE name = '"+ name +"' ", function(err, rows, fields){

        if(bcryptjs.compareSync(req.body.pass, rows[0].password)){
            console.log('Login');
            req.session.name = true;
            res.render('Home/:name' , { name: name });
        }else{
            errors.push({ msg: 'Wrong Password' });
        }
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            if(rows.length <= 0){
                    errors.push({ msg: 'Wrong Username' });
            }   
        }
        if(errors.length > 0){
            res.render('login',{
                errors,
                name,
                pass
            });
        }
    });
    });
});
```

This is login.ejs form im using post method without adding action.

```
<form method="POST" class="register-form" id="login-form">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="your_name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="your_name" placeholder="Your Name" value="<%= typeof name != 'undefined' ? name : '' %>" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="your_pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="your_pass" placeholder="Password" value="<%= typeof pass != 'undefined' ? pass : '' %>" />
</div>
<div class="form-group form-button">
<input type="submit" name="signin" id="signin" class="form-submit" value="Log in" />
</div>
</form>
```

Im getting this error

Failed to lookup view "Home/:name" in views derectory

Comment: it fails to find Home.ejs in your view directory. Have you created Home.ejs in your view directory?

Comment: Yes I created Home.ejs

Comment: Please remove your [first same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60032492/how-to-show-username-in-url-after-post-form-in-express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res.redirect(`Home/${name}`);
```

You're in a post request and want to redirect in a get route....

Comment: Thank You So Much Sir Im Stuck in This For More Than 1 week