# Cannot GET /login - It used to work, nothing was changed, now I get this

Tags: node.js, express

A corporate partner developed this app--using Node.js and Express.js--which gets used about once a month for demos.  In December it worked fine, now when trying to access the app it returns "Cannot GET /login."  Running the app on multiple systems has the same result.

I'm at a loss as to where to start troubleshooting; any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

This is the only reference to the /login endpoint:

```
function gotoLogin() {
    window.location.href = window.$data.config.API_SERVER + "/login"
}
```

After reading [Cannot GET /login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058646/cannot-get-login), I altered the Express.js app as such:

Original:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('app-template.njk')
})
```

Altered:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  res.render('app-template.njk')
})
```

I no longer get "Cannot GET /login," but it adds /login before every endpoint i.e. https://localhost:8080/login/login, which throws off everything else:  assets, css, js, etc.

Comment: 1: I think the prefix depends on either use of a Router defined under /login or use of static files in the project structure. Can you see express.static('/login', xxxx) or app.use('/login', xxxx) somewhere?

Comment: Express.js do not implement the Windows convention of wildchatr so this '/*' will not work as you may think. * is a RegEx operator

Comment: Furthermore you should show the entire routing structure for us to help you